# iOS bluetooth: Unknown error when writing to characteristic

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my application I discover my peripheral with a given service. I then check that all characteristics wanted are present before moving on.

When I write a value to my characteristics, the callback `didWriteValueForCharacteristic:` trigger:

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Did write characteristic value : %@ with ID %@", characteristic.value, characteristic.UUID);
    NSLog(@"With error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

and yields this output:

```
Did write characteristic value : <005c> with ID Unknown (<00005004 1212efde 1523785f eabcd123>)
With error: Unknown error.
```

The value is correct, same goes for the 128bit UUID of the characteristic, but in my peripheral I never actually get a value written.

Any suggestions to what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you have in the *Console* a message like: *CoreBluetooth[WARNING]*. Sometimes the real error is given there. And I still don't know why and how to catch them...

Comment: Not at the time. Answered my own question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I originally sent a `WriteWithoutResponse`, changing this to `WriteWithResponse` gave me a `CoreBluetooth[WARNING] error 13` as mentioned by @Larme in the comments. This value [corresponded to](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Constants/Reference/reference.html) Invalid Attribute Value Length, meaning I sent the wrong number format, i.e I sent a 16bit value while the peripheral expected 8bit.

Changing the peripheral to accept 16bit data solved the issue.

Comment: How did you discover that error 13 means "Invalid attribute value length"?  I've been searching everywhere for a list of these error codes, with no luck.  (I'm getting unknown error 10.)

Comment: @JoeStrout http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Constants/Reference/reference.html your error is `CBATTErrorAttributeNotFound`

Comment: But What is the solution?

Comment: @Mrug sending the correct value format solved the issue

Comment: Can you please help me on a issue related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095333/corebluetooth-writing-data-from-central-to-peripheral

Comment: I am using WriteWithResponse, also getting Unknown Error

Comment: We are able to send data properly after connection but sometimes it becomes not ready to send (Connection is still). Do you know what causes this issue?  @chwi