# CoreBluetooth - Writing data from Central to Peripheral

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

I referred Sample app provided by Apple for CoreBluetooth and I succeeded in sending Data from Peripheral to Central, Now I need to write Data from Central to Peripheral. After Googling i found that It can be done using `[_discoveredPeripheral writeValue:aData forCharacteristic:charc type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];`

Following is my Implementation of Central, to send Message to peripheral:

```
-(void)sendMessage:(NSString *)strMessage{
    NSData *aData = [strMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CBMutableCharacteristic *charc =[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite value:nil permissions: CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
    [_discoveredPeripheral writeValue:aData forCharacteristic:charc type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];        
}
```

When I call this method, It is not able to write data, instead of that I can see a CoreBluetooth Warning on console as below,

```
CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBMutableCharacteristic: 0x15e8e420 UUID = 08590F7E-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4, Value = (null), Properties = 0x8, Permissions = 0x2, Descriptors = (null), SubscribedCentrals = (
)> is not a valid characteristic for peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x15d91250 identifier = 37C314AF-FDB3-1F24-6937-8780B97AAB45, Name = "iPad", state = disconnected>
```

It would be nice if someone give the best way to get Object of Peripheral  and how to initiate sending of data from  Central to Peripheral.

**EDIT**
I have tried the way that is shown in [How to get the characteristic from UUID in objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737179/how-to-get-the-characteristic-from-uuid-in-objective-c)

But, In this case I am not able to Loop Services whenever I try for that It returns services=nil.

Comment: You have to scan the characteristics, save it in a iVar, and then use this one to do: `[_discoveredPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:charcFoundByScan type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the characteristic from UUID in objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737179/how-to-get-the-characteristic-from-uuid-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Larme: I tried this too, but for traversing services when I loop _discoveredPeripheral.services it return count 0. So not able to proceed loop.

Comment: You need to show this code. When you do `_discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;` in `didDiscoverPeripheral:`, you need to do: `[_discoveredPeripheral scanForServices:nil]`; And then loop again in the delegate method etc. You should look at the Apple's sample code (Thermometer, etc.) about CoreBluetooth.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and now atleast, now I can make successful call of writeValue. But now new issue has arrived. In Delegate "didWriteValueForCharacteristic" I am receiving Error.
`Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown error." UserInfo=0x14ea3e10 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error.}`

Comment: Does the characteristic supports "WithResponse"?

Comment: Yes, Its done bro. The issue was related to permission. It was read, where as, i should use write permission.BTW Thanks @Larme